# How do I make floor plans from photographs?

Tags: image-processing, 3d

I'm looking for software or an online service that can take multiple photos of the inside of a house and create a 2D or 3D floor plan. Such software has been under development by the computer vision research scientists since the 1990s. I've seen it demonstrated. Is such software now available to consumers?

Comment: If you don't mind moving through the models online you can try photosynth.net

Comment: This happens to deal with pictures, but doesn't relate to photography at all.  I'm thinking it should be more in the space of Super User.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iphone App: [MagicPlan app magically creates interactive floor plans](http://www.tuaw.com/2011/04/13/magicplan-app-magically-creates-interactive-floor-plans/)

> Sensopia's MagicPlan works with the iPhone 4 and fourth-generation iPod touch. To build a floor plan, you go into each room and take a picture of each corner of the room. By doing that, MagicPlan measures the walls and doors in the room, and it creates a floor plan of each room. You then slide the rooms into their proper location by dragging them on the screen, and MagicPlan aligns the rooms and manages the thickness of the walls.

Seems cool to me :)

Comment: That's insanely great!

Comment: This link is out of date.